# What is correct form to write A,E,I,O syllogistic relations in predicative form?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to draw a simple and comprehensive chart about syllogisms for my collegues. I need to represent relations like "All cows are mammals" in predicative form and draw Euler's diagram (not a problem) for it. I think about something that looks like (C - cows, M - mammals):
$$
\forall a\in C:P(a \in M)
$$
But I'm not really sure about it. It would be really cool to have some examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Aristotle's Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#AllSomNon):

$Aab$ is a shorthand for "$a$ belongs to all $b$" and we read it as "Every $b$ is $a$".

Thus:

> $Aab$ will be $\forall x (b(x) \to a(x))$.

$Iab$ is "$a$ belongs to some $b$" and we read it as "Some $b$ is $a$".

Thus:

> $Iab$ will be $\exists x (b(x) \land a(x))$.

And similar for those involving negation.

You can also use [restricted quantifiers](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Restricted_quantifier): $(\forall x : b)a(x)$ that, using a "mixed" symbolization using $\in$ will be : $(\forall x \in b) a(x)$.

---

Switching from predicates to their extensions (i.e. sets or classes), we have that:

> $Aab$ is $b \subseteq a$

while:

> $Iab$ is $b \cap a \ne \emptyset$.